# Visual Studio 2010 bookmarks

Tags: bookmarks, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to use bookmarks in Vs2010. The way I understand them is, I can place bookmarks at points throughout my project and then use them to quickly navigate to points of interest. When I attempt to place a bookmarks, both through the edit menu and the quick keys, nothing happens.

I understand this is probably a silly question with a simple and obvious answer.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I was trying to place a bookmark with the enable feature not the toggle feature. Case solved.

I already applied my palm to forehead, no need for ridicule :)